# Not able to get YahooEarningsCalendar to work

Tags: python

I am trying to run a sample code from [here](https://pypi.org/project/yahoo-earnings-calendar/):

```
import datetime
from yahoo_earnings_calendar import YahooEarningsCalendar

date_from = datetime.datetime.strptime(
    'May 5 2017  10:00AM', '%b %d %Y %I:%M%p')
date_to = datetime.datetime.strptime(
    'May 8 2017  1:00PM', '%b %d %Y %I:%M%p')
yec = YahooEarningsCalendar()
print(yec.earnings_on(date_from))
print(yec.earnings_between(date_from, date_to))
```

I had tried to change the dates but either way I am getting these two errors:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

or

```
Exception: Invalid Symbol or Unavailable Earnings Date
```

Could you please advise if this error is on my end or if this package has stopped working?

Answer (score 0):

The issue occurs because the page got by `requests.get(url)` in `_get_data_dict(url)` in yahoo_earnings_calendar/scraper.py is broken as the yahoo server may only accept HTTP GET from browsers like Chrome or Firefox

so to fix that, you can add `"user-agent"` into a header and pass it to `requests.get()` in `_get_data_dict()` in yahoo_earnings_calendar/scraper.py

```
url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/calendar/earnings?day=2017-05-05&offset=1&size=1'
import json
header = {
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36",
}
def _get_data_dict(url):
        #time.sleep(self.delay)
        page = requests.get(url,headers=header)
        page_content = page.content.decode(encoding='utf-8', errors='strict')
        print(page_content)
        page_data_string = [row for row in page_content.split(
            '\n') if row.startswith('root.App.main = ')][0][:-1]
        page_data_string = page_data_string.split('root.App.main = ', 1)[1]
        return json.loads(page_data_string)
```